# How to combine two projects made under different API level?

Tags: android, api

I m creating a customised music player with some additional features in it.... for that i copied one project whose API level is 10 and pasted it in my current working project whose API level is 19..... i m getting an error "Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 10"...... I don't know how to make two API level work in the same project ..... please help....... i tried cleaning my project and rebuilding it ..... but after that it shows R cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the api level on the project, in your project manifest you will find this line:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Change the targetSdkVersion to 19 to make it work with Android 4.4.

Comment: Have you set it to 19 for both projects?

Comment: no.... i only set it for the project in which i imported the 1st project ........and after i did that ....errors are gone .... but i also  changed my compliler compilance level to 1.6 from 1.7 in order to solve the errors......Thnxx a lot @da_st ...... coz of u i can proceed ahead  finally  on my project ....

Comment: @Jacksy if this solved your problem please accept the answer! :)